# Parameters of the 'cat' command

Tags: text, cat

```
cat -b test1.txt
```

This command is meant to skip blank lines and number the rest.

```
cat -n test1.txt
```

This command numbers lines no matter what.

I tried both of them. One on a file with only spaces and tabs and other with some alphabets. Both of them numbered both the files identically. Is filling a file with spaces and tabs a way to create an empty line or am I doing it wrong?

**Update**

I don't know what is even unclear in this. So here is how I reached http://askubuntu.com

I was reading I was reading the book *Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible by Richard Blum*. It had mentioned this:

[image]

So I tried to do that. I thought empty lines should only contain tabs or spaces. So I created a file with tabs and spaces (in order to have an empty line). So I tried running this command:

```
cat -b test1.txt
```

However, it still numbered the lines which contained only tabs and spaces.
So I knew that tabs and spaces were still being counted as characters. I asked a question here for how to add a blank line in a text file for the code:

```
cat -b text1.txt
```

to work.

This is the best I can do to explain my question.

Comment: `cat` doesn't add anything to any file. It lists file contents. So the question makes no sense. You could simply ask how to add an empty line to a file.

Comment: Not with the cat command. Try  `sed` http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/?ref=driverlayer.com#insert_lines

Comment: @Pilot6 I meant to say that when it reads and displays the content of the file, -b and -n number the line before displaying it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and write there what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did so.

Comment: why the heck did you make a comment out of your question?!

Comment: Now the question is unclear.

Comment: If you want some answer ask a question in a way it is answerable.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't realise till now that the question was  very unclear. I clarified it now.

Comment: Now it is even more unclear. You never mention what you want to achieve. You tried some commands, didn't like the output for some reason. The last sentence is 100% unclear.

Comment: At least you tried, but it's still very unclear what you're up to. Does my answer below help? If not, please explain what an empty line means for you and where you want it to appear.

Comment: @Pilot6 I thought the question was clear now. But your answer probably is the solution. I haven't tried it yet. But yeah, I have clarified the question even further. That's the best I can do to explain.

Comment: Line with Tabs and Spaces isn't empty. An empty line contains nothing.

Comment: @Pilot6 And that's what's **actually** and finally answers OP's question – add it to your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an empty line to a file called "file_name" by running

```
echo >> file_name
```

An empty line is a line that contains literally nothing including tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Adding blank lines in a text file can be done by:

- Opening the text file in an editor
- Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
- Save the file

Comment: Will not the enter key still be considered as a character?

Comment: This is also a good way to add an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

To have a blank line inserted in your output, just first output the first part of your file, then run `echo` and then output the second part.

E.g. for a file `test`:

```
> cat test
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
> head -2 test && echo && tail -n+3 test
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4
```

You could define a function to automate this, something like:

```
> blank_line(){ head -$(bc <<< $1-1) $2 && echo && tail -n+$1 $2;}
> blank_line 2 test
line 1

line 2
line 3
line 4
```

As you can see, this simple function takes the line number where the blank line should be displayed as the first and the filename as the second argument.